# $\left( \varphi_1, ..., \varphi_p \right)$ linearly independent iff some linear application is surjective

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $E$ a $\mathbf{K}$ vector space (not necessarily finite-dimensional) , $p \geq 1$ and $\left( \varphi_1, ...,  \varphi_p \right)$ a family of elements of $E^\star$ (set of linear functions from $E$ to $\mathbf{K}$).

Let

$$
\Phi : 
\left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
        E & \rightarrow & \mathbf{K}^p \\
        x & \mapsto & \left( \varphi_1(x), ...,  \varphi_p(x) \right)
    \end{array}
\right.
$$

I want to show the following equivalence:

$\left( \varphi_1, ...,  \varphi_p \right)$ is linearly independent $\Leftrightarrow$ $\Phi$  is surjective

I have already proved that if $\Phi$ is surjective, then the family of functions is  linearly independent. I would like to show the other implication now.

I tried to prove it by contradiction: assume $\Phi(E) \neq \mathbf{K}^p$. Let $y_1, ..., y_s$ be a basis of $\Phi(E)$ with $s < p$. We can find linear applications $\lambda_k : \Phi(E) \mapsto \mathbf{K}$ such that for all $x \in E$:

$$
\left( \varphi_1(x), ...,  \varphi_p(x) \right) = \lambda_1(x)y_1 + ... + \lambda_s(x)y_s
$$

Using that, I would like to find a relation of linear dependence between the $\varphi_i$s. But I do not know how to do this. Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's go for your proof by contradiction/contrapositive: we want to show that if $\Phi(E) \neq K^p$, then the $\varphi_i$ must fail to be linearly independent.

If $\Phi(E)$ is a proper subset of $K^p$, then there exists a non-zero linear map $\alpha:K^p \to K$ such that $\Phi(E) \subset \ker\alpha$, or equivalently such that $\alpha \circ \Phi = 0$.  Now, $\alpha$ must have the form
$$
\alpha(y) = a_1 y_1 + \cdots + a_p y_p, \qquad y = (y_1,\dots,y_p) \in K^p
$$
for some coefficients $a_i$ with at least one non-zero.  Thus, we may now state that for all $x$, we have
$$
0 = (\alpha \circ \Phi)(x) = a_1 \varphi_1(x) + \cdots + a_p \varphi_p(x),
$$
which is to say that $a_1 \varphi_1 + \cdots + a_p \varphi_p = 0$.  Thus, we conclude that the $\varphi_i$ are indeed linearly dependent.